# NanoPi with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed, turns off by itself

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, dmesg

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Nanopi NEO Plus 2 and it worked fine, later I installed ROS(Robot Operating System) on it and it begin shutting down by itself after 15-20 minutes. I ran the 'dmesg' command but couldn't understand where the issue is:

```
Last login: Thu Jul  1 09:44:14 2021 from 192.168.43.187
root@NanoPi-NEO-Plus2:~# dmesg
[    0.017809] vdso: 2 pages (1 code @ ffff000008996000, 1 data @ ffff000008d44000)
[    0.017823] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.018806] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic allocations
[    0.018868] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.030105] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.031626] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.031780] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.031814] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.031860] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.032037] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.032061] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.032129] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.032134] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.032147] PTP clock support registered
[    0.032375] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.033490] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.033696] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.033750] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.033854] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.034010] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.038861] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.039254] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.039324] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.039488] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.039594] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.039623] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.039767] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.040082] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.040088] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.040092] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.040097] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.040287] Unpacking initramfs...
[    0.305634] Freeing initrd memory: 6136K
[    0.309739] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.309860] audit: type=2000 audit(0.308:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.310101] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[    0.315346] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.315722] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.315746] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.315750] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.315761] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.315766] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[    0.320760] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    0.320923] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 246)
[    0.321007] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.321013] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.321139] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.321145] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.321150] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.321688] sun4i-usb-phy 1c19400.phy: Couldn't request ID GPIO, pinctrl may not init
[    0.323220] sun8i-h3-r-pinctrl 1f02c00.pinctrl: initialized sunXi PIO driver
[    0.325727] sun50i-h5-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: initialized sunXi PIO driver
[    0.331639] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.332554] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.352685] 1c28000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c28000 (irq = 32, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    1.102858] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.128640] 1c28400.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x1c28400 (irq = 33, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    1.159761] 1c28800.serial: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x1c28800 (irq = 34, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    1.189178] 1c28c00.serial: ttyS3 at MMIO 0x1c28c00 (irq = 35, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    1.200096] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.206713] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    1.219540] sun4i-drm display-engine: bound 1100000.mixer (ops sun8i_mixer_ops)
[    1.227012] sun4i-drm display-engine: No panel or bridge found... RGB output disabled
[    1.234849] sun4i-drm display-engine: bound 1c0c000.lcd-controller (ops sun4i_tcon_ops)
[    1.365548] sun8i-dw-hdmi 1ee0000.hdmi: Detected HDMI TX controller v1.32a with HDCP (sun8i_dw_hdmi_phy)
[    1.375288] sun8i-dw-hdmi 1ee0000.hdmi: registered DesignWare HDMI I2C bus driver
[    1.382933] sun4i-drm display-engine: bound 1ee0000.hdmi (ops sun8i_dw_hdmi_ops)
[    1.390357] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1920x1080
[    1.429904] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    1.463191] sun4i-drm display-engine: fb0:  frame buffer device
[    1.469425] [drm] Initialized sun4i-drm 1.0.0 20150629 for display-engine on minor 0
[    1.478066] cacheinfo: Unable to detect cache hierarchy for CPU 0
[    1.487498] loop: module loaded
[    1.492318] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.497024] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: PTP uses main clock
[    1.503062] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.507436] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[    1.512145] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
[    1.517232] PPP MPPE Compression module registered
[    1.522023] NET: Registered protocol family 24
[    1.526484] PPTP driver version 0.8.5
[    1.530430] usbcore: registered new interface driver qmi_wwan
[    1.536412] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.542937] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.548307] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.553893] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.562154] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: irq 14, io mem 0x01c1a000
[    1.581500] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.588184] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.591963] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.596429] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.602628] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    1.608007] ohci-platform 1c1a400.usb: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    1.614632] ohci-platform 1c1a400.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.622626] ohci-platform 1c1a400.usb: irq 15, io mem 0x01c1a400
[    1.690009] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.693793] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.698295] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    1.703959] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    1.711982] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[    1.717665] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.723029] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.729086] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    1.734940] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    1.741493] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    1.747517] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[    1.753100] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[    1.760151] usbcore: registered new interface driver qcserial
[    1.765909] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Qualcomm USB modem
[    1.773386] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.779317] sun6i-rtc 1f00000.rtc: rtc core: registered rtc-sun6i as rtc0
[    1.786103] sun6i-rtc 1f00000.rtc: RTC enabled
[    1.790591] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.795331] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 244
[    1.801688] IR NEC protocol handler initialized
[    1.806216] IR RC5(x/sz) protocol handler initialized
[    1.811263] IR RC6 protocol handler initialized
[    1.815792] IR JVC protocol handler initialized
[    1.820319] IR Sony protocol handler initialized
[    1.824942] IR SANYO protocol handler initialized
[    1.829647] IR Sharp protocol handler initialized
[    1.834348] IR MCE Keyboard/mouse protocol handler initialized
[    1.840177] IR LIRC bridge handler initialized
[    1.844619] IR XMP protocol handler initialized
[    1.849200] usbcore: registered new interface driver ati_remote
[    1.855245] usbcore: registered new interface driver imon
[    1.860674] usbcore: registered new interface driver mceusb
[    1.866273] usbcore: registered new interface driver redrat3
[    1.871975] usbcore: registered new interface driver streamzap
[    1.877893] usbcore: registered new interface driver igorplugusb
[    1.883921] usbcore: registered new interface driver iguanair
[    1.889687] usbcore: registered new interface driver ttusbir
[    1.895916] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-16)
[    1.902967] sunxi-wdt 1c20ca0.watchdog: Watchdog enabled (timeout=16 sec, nowayout=0)
[    1.911394] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.917574] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.921953] Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver
[    1.965509] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.mmc: initialized, max. request size: 16384 KB, uses new timings mode
[    1.975235] sunxi-mmc 1c10000.mmc: allocated mmc-pwrseq
[    2.026702] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.038145] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 5048
[    2.044069] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD32G 28.9 GiB 
[    2.049426]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
[    2.225510] sunxi-mmc 1c10000.mmc: initialized, max. request size: 16384 KB, uses new timings mode
[    2.261836] mmc2: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    2.270277] mmc2: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.273504] sunxi-mmc 1c11000.mmc: initialized, max. request size: 2048 KB, uses new timings mode
[    2.284854] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.291481] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.297709] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.303297] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.308866] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.313719] mmc2: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.324522] mmc2: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    2.330521] sun4i-codec 1c22c00.codec: Codec <-> 1c22c00.codec mapping ok
[    2.338984] gre: GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
[    2.343876] ip_gre: GRE over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.349458] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    2.355102] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.365316] mmc2: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x81 (9 bytes)
[    2.371128] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.374881] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.379403] l2tp_core: L2TP core driver, V2.0
[    2.383777] l2tp_ppp: PPPoL2TP kernel driver, V2.0
[    2.388573] l2tp_netlink: L2TP netlink interface
[    2.393746] rfkill_gpio rfkill_bt: sunxi-bt device registered.
[    2.399660] 9pnet: Installing 9P2000 support
[    2.403985] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.408894] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.418130] Key type encrypted registered
[    2.427945] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: PTP uses main clock
[    2.433822] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Will use external PHY
[    2.443715] mmc1: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
[    2.449560] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 8GTF4R 7.28 GiB 
[    2.454325] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 8GTF4R partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    2.460451] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 8GTF4R partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    2.467091]  mmcblk1: p1 p2 p3
[    2.504381] random: fast init done
[    2.545649] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Chain mode enabled
[    2.551314] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: No HW DMA feature register supported
[    2.558540] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Normal descriptors
[    2.564202] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: RX Checksum Offload Engine supported
[    2.571425] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: COE Type 2
[    2.576394] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: TX Checksum insertion supported
[    2.583694] libphy: stmmac: probed
[    2.591020] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.596628] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    2.604980] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: irq 16, io mem 0x01c1b000
[    2.625496] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.632133] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.635918] hub 3-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.640419] ehci-platform 1c1c000.usb: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.646014] ehci-platform 1c1c000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    2.654202] ehci-platform 1c1c000.usb: irq 18, io mem 0x01c1c000
[    2.673496] ehci-platform 1c1c000.usb: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.680038] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.683817] hub 4-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.688271] ehci-platform 1c1d000.usb: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.693861] ehci-platform 1c1d000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    2.702062] ehci-platform 1c1d000.usb: irq 20, io mem 0x01c1d000
[    2.721495] ehci-platform 1c1d000.usb: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.728038] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.731817] hub 5-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.736247] ohci-platform 1c1b400.usb: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    2.742879] ohci-platform 1c1b400.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    2.750905] ohci-platform 1c1b400.usb: irq 17, io mem 0x01c1b400
[    2.761218] mmc2: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    2.817948] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.821724] hub 6-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.826175] ohci-platform 1c1c400.usb: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    2.832799] ohci-platform 1c1c400.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    2.840843] ohci-platform 1c1c400.usb: irq 19, io mem 0x01c1c400
[    2.909942] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.913717] hub 7-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.918137] ohci-platform 1c1d400.usb: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    2.924761] ohci-platform 1c1d400.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[    2.932785] ohci-platform 1c1d400.usb: irq 21, io mem 0x01c1d400
[    3.001938] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.005713] hub 8-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    3.010235] usb_phy_generic usb_phy_generic.3.auto: usb_phy_generic.3.auto supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.021173] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.4.auto: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    3.026924] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.4.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 9
[    3.035240] hub 9-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.039024] hub 9-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    3.045408] input: r-gpio-keys as /devices/platform/r-gpio-keys/input/input0
[    3.052826] ALSA device list:
[    3.055802]   #0: Dummy 1
[    3.058426]   #1: Loopback 1
[    3.061299]   #2: H3 Audio Codec
[    3.064990] Freeing unused kernel memory: 512K
[    3.069509] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform
[    3.598095] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.836927] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.852413] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
[    4.581329] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    4.632091] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.7 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    4.654962] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm64.
[    4.690762] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <NanoPi-NEO-Plus2>.
[    5.341370] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service:11: Support for option SysVStartPriority= has been removed and it is ignored
[    5.417139] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    5.424085] systemd[1]: system-modprobe.slice: unit configures an IP firewall, but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup firewalling.
[    5.436687] systemd[1]: (This warning is only shown for the first unit using IP firewalling.)
[    5.447435] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[    5.465633] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    5.473411] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.494328] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    5.501937] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    5.518599] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    5.545815] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    5.574676] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    5.601827] systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[    5.622685] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    5.641594] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    5.661672] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    5.681636] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    5.697931] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    5.719922] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    5.737963] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.759079] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.778215] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    5.793948] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.815026] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    5.838854] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    5.862256] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    5.878938] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Trace File System being skipped.
[    5.894444] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    5.913684] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[    5.935252] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    5.961802] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[    5.978704] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    5.994643] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    6.017759] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    6.044972] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    6.068601] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    6.121200] udc-core: couldn't find an available UDC - added [g_mass_storage] to list of pending drivers
[    6.247156] 8821cu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    6.266011] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8821cu
[    6.292136] systemd-journald[285]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    6.323610] Adding 524284k swap on /mnt/512MB.swap.  Priority:-2 extents:5 across:557052k SS
[    6.494288] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88xxau
[    6.532370] systemd-journald[285]: File /var/log/journal/7028ac97459541d7aad9d2021a3707e8/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[    6.569397] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[    6.777297] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[    6.786578] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[    6.798064] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Jun 12 2019 21:30:19 version 7.46.58.28 (r717266 CY) FWID 01-d43eaba6 es4.c3.n4
[    8.131017] asoc-simple-card soc:sound: i2s-hifi <-> 1c22800.i2s mapping ok
[    8.209913] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[    8.297680] usb 5-1: Vendor: Realtek
[    8.297689] usb 5-1: Product: #802.11n NI
[    8.297693] usb 5-1: Serial: 
[    8.297698] usb 5-1: rtl8192eu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[    8.297702] usb 5-1: 00: 29 81 00 7c 01 40 03 00
[    8.297706] usb 5-1: 08: 40 74 04 50 14 00 00 00
[    8.297709] usb 5-1: 10: 27 26 26 28 28 28 20 26
[    8.297713] usb 5-1: 18: 25 25 25 e0 ef ef ff ff
[    8.297716] usb 5-1: 20: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297720] usb 5-1: 28: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297723] usb 5-1: 30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297727] usb 5-1: 38: ff ff 2b 29 29 2b 2b 2b
[    8.297731] usb 5-1: 40: 23 29 26 27 27 e0 ef ef
[    8.297734] usb 5-1: 48: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297738] usb 5-1: 50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297741] usb 5-1: 58: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297745] usb 5-1: 60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297748] usb 5-1: 68: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297752] usb 5-1: 70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297755] usb 5-1: 78: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297758] usb 5-1: 80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297762] usb 5-1: 88: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297765] usb 5-1: 90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297769] usb 5-1: 98: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297772] usb 5-1: a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297776] usb 5-1: a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297779] usb 5-1: b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297782] usb 5-1: b8: 20 22 1f 00 00 00 ff ff
[    8.297786] usb 5-1: c0: ff 01 00 10 00 00 00 ff
[    8.297789] usb 5-1: c8: 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297793] usb 5-1: d0: da 0b 8b 81 e7 47 02 50
[    8.297796] usb 5-1: d8: 2b 73 c0 4c dc 0a 03 52
[    8.297799] usb 5-1: e0: 65 61 6c 74 65 6b 20 0e
[    8.297803] usb 5-1: e8: 03 38 30 32 2e 31 31 6e
[    8.297806] usb 5-1: f0: 20 4e 49 43 20 00 ff ff
[    8.297810] usb 5-1: f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297813] usb 5-1: 100: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297817] usb 5-1: 108: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297820] usb 5-1: 110: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0d
[    8.297823] usb 5-1: 118: 03 00 05 00 30 00 00 00
[    8.297827] usb 5-1: 120: 00 93 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297830] usb 5-1: 128: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297834] usb 5-1: 130: f6 a8 98 2d 03 92 98 00
[    8.297837] usb 5-1: 138: fc 8c 00 11 9b 44 02 0a
[    8.297841] usb 5-1: 140: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297844] usb 5-1: 148: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297848] usb 5-1: 150: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297851] usb 5-1: 158: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297855] usb 5-1: 160: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297859] usb 5-1: 168: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297862] usb 5-1: 170: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297866] usb 5-1: 178: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297869] usb 5-1: 180: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297872] usb 5-1: 188: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297876] usb 5-1: 190: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297880] usb 5-1: 198: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297883] usb 5-1: 1a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297887] usb 5-1: 1a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297890] usb 5-1: 1b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297894] usb 5-1: 1b8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297898] usb 5-1: 1c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297901] usb 5-1: 1c8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297905] usb 5-1: 1d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297908] usb 5-1: 1d8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297912] usb 5-1: 1e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297916] usb 5-1: 1e8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297920] usb 5-1: 1f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297923] usb 5-1: 1f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[    8.297931] usb 5-1: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[    8.297935] usb 5-1: RTL8192EU MAC: 50:2b:73:c0:4c:dc
[    8.297941] usb 5-1: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[    8.298054] usb 5-1: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin failed with error -2
[    8.298061] usb 5-1: request_firmware(rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin) failed
[    8.298066] usb 5-1: Fatal - failed to load firmware
[    8.303537] rtl8xxxu: probe of 5-1:1.0 failed with error -11
[    8.303614] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[   10.111344] i2c i2c-0: mv64xxx: I2C bus locked, block: 1, time_left: 0
[   10.116447] rtc-ds1307: probe of 0-0068 failed with error -110
[   11.277067] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   11.278300] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet stmmac-0:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=stmmac-0:00, irq=POLL)
[   11.286028] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet eth0: No MAC Management Counters available
[   11.286041] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet eth0: PTP not supported by HW
[   11.286500] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   11.324144] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   11.364777] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   14.073958] random: crng init done
[   14.073967] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   14.185309] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   15.373050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   16.810033] IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::f5e0:1622:f74f:77b0 detected!
[   16.976388] IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::f5fe:d5c7:f8dd:90d4 detected!
[   19.944398] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   19.944525] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   19.944528] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.944544] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.944553] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.944586] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.964151] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   19.964164] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   19.964166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   19.964168] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   19.964386] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   19.964389] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   19.964391] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   19.964393] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   20.535054] systemd-journald[285]: File /var/log/journal/7028ac97459541d7aad9d2021a3707e8/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   35.078592] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   44.622116] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   44.622124] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   44.622142] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   44.679391] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   44.679424] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   44.679451] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  187.034499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  238.682866] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Which OS are you asking about?  Ubuntu Core 20? or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  They are different systems (Ubuntu Core is *snap* only, has a 10 year supported life without need of ESM, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is *deb* based but can also use *snaps*, has a 5 year supported life which can be extended via ESM etc)

Comment: Edited: It's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: You've still got the Ubuntu-Core tag which is a different product to 20.04..

Comment: How did you even install Ubuntu on a NanoPi? I'm interested in doing that but nobody knows how. Only Raspberry Pi seems to be supported somehow.